# Using SOAP 1.1 instead of 1.2

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio, soap

I am making a call to a SOAP web service in Visual Studio, using Service References. I believe that Visual Studio defaults to using SOAP 1.2. The service I am consuming is SOAP 1.1. Is there any way to force Visual Studio to use the SOAP 1.1 protocol?

I am quite new to SOAP, and appreciate any suggestions you may have

.NET version is 4.5

Thank you

Chris

Comment: How are you consuming your service?

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.soapversion(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks very much, Googled for a couple of hours but I must've missed that post!